# using 7.62mm screw terminals on prototype board

Tags: hobbyist

What have people done to be able to use 7.62mm screw terminals on prototype boards?  I am trying to prototype something use screw terminals that have 7.62mm posts, but the prototype boards do not have holes that large.

Comment: Some sort of drill would probably do the job.

Comment: So drill the holes bigger.

Comment: That was my initial thought, just wanted further confirmation.  Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a lot more information: What prototype board? Why do you expect it to be able to take 7.62mm terminals? What type of connector do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a PCB supplier who isn't so picky (there are MANY suppliers), or drill them out yourself (and sacrifice through-hole plating).